# Advanced Fetching Alchemist II

Tags: mathematics, optimization, graph-theory, video-games

[image]

This is a puzzle in the [Fetching Alchemist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bizleycraft.fetchingalchemist) series. From now on, you complete quests at the place you start at as well.

Please note that, in my opinion, imperfect solutions should be up-voted so long as they work and are lower than previous guesses. This makes them useful, since they inform other players of whether they have a possible solution or not.

---

### How to Play

You are looking for the shortest possible path that allows you to complete all the quests. You choose where you start. The red numbers indicate the distance of each road. Present your answer in the form "99: ABCDE...", where the numbers are the total path distance and the letters are the place you started at followed by the places you visit on the path.

You complete a quest by either starting there or travelling there with the required items in your inventory, which are consumed upon completing the quest (if the quest has required items, indicated by the presence of items left of an arrow under the quest).

The items drawn around places are the reward items for the quests that can be completed there.

You can complete a quest more than once but only once per place.

You cannot avoid completing a quest that you are able to complete where you are. This includes when you have no need for the quest reward.

You can complete more than one quest in the same place. When completing more than one quest in the same place, quests are completed automatically from top to bottom. Consequently, completing a higher quest may prevent completing a lower quest.

If you would obtain an item from completing a quest, you can use it to complete a quest in the same place without travelling again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have a better way.

> Start at C, for the summer reagent materials.  Two steps to L brews the reagent and also gives you the waxcaps.  Two more gives you the second sage, and brews the essence of fire.  Two more gets you to G for the turn-in.  Total of 6.

> 83: CFLJBCG

Comment: Hey Ben could you possibly write out all the letters in the format "ABCD" so I can see clearly your path?

Comment: @JoshuaBizley how's that?

Comment: That's the correct answer! You don't need to write the letters twice in a row but I know what you mean. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

This one was fairly straightforward, but I like the different feel.
First of all, the obvious starting point is

> I, because it's the only way to get Waxcaps without backtracking. From there a simple step to B nets us the Essence of Fire and another step to C gets the ingredients for the Summer Reagent.

From there, it's simple distance-checking:

> CL is shorter than CJ and G is clearly a closer destination than D, so our path is
>  **86: IBCFLFCG**

Comment: Good job Axi but there is a quicker way!

Comment: Agh, didn't see the waxcaps at L...

Answer (score 1):

> Run a loop on the right hand side starting from C and finish at G
> 83: CFLJBCG